# How to assign and manage a priority mechanism

Tags: python, django, algorithm, design-patterns

I am working on a `Django` web application where users create a list of tasks. Each task is a record in the database (ie: a Django object) and the user is able to assign each task a priority.

If the user creates 10 tasks, each of them would have a priority from 1 to 10. I'm struggling to figure out an efficient way to allow users to change the priority of tasks as well as insert and delete tasks. For example:

- A user moves task priority 3 down to 7. The other tasks priorities need to be adjusted accordingly.
- A user deletes task with priority 4. Once again the remaining tasks priorities would need to be adjusted.
- A user inserts a new task with priority 5. This means the existing tasks from priority 5 onwards need to be shifted.

Are there any design patterns or suggestions on how to manage what essentially amounts to a queue based on the priority of each item while allowing users to:

- Move tasks up and down the priority list
- Delete tasks
- Add new tasks with specified priorities.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to assign numbers to the priority. You can just use strings that have in theory infinite resolution.

```
item      index
-----------------
gizmo     1
              <<------ Oh no! no room between 1 and 2.
                       This requires incrementing _every_ item after it
gadget    2
gear      3
toolkit   4
box       5
```

But here if you count by 100s:

```
item      index
-----------------
gizmo     100
              <<------ Sweet :). I can re-order 99 (!) items here
                       without having to change anything else
gadget    200
gear      300
toolkit   400
box       500
```

Even better: here is how Jira solves this problem. Their "rank" (what you call index) is a string value that allows a ton of breathing room in between ranked items.

Here is a real example of a jira database I work with

```
   id    | jira_rank
---------+------------
 AP-2405 | 0|hzztxk:
 ES-213  | 0|hzztxs:
 AP-2660 | 0|hzztzc:
 AP-2688 | 0|hzztzk:
 AP-2643 | 0|hzztzs:
 AP-2208 | 0|hzztzw:
 AP-2700 | 0|hzztzy:
 AP-2702 | 0|hzztzz:
 AP-2411 | 0|hzztzz:i
 AP-2440 | 0|hzztzz:r
```

Notice this example hzztzz:i. The advantage of a string rank is that you run out of room between two items, you still don't have to re-rank anything else. You just start appending more characters to the string to narrow down focus.
Based on the answer from [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/369754/253703)

Although saying all that [this](https://github.com/django-ordered-model/django-ordered-model) package that is fairly used, actually uses a positive integer and issues SQL to update all the following order numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you working so hard to build queues? Can't you just use .order_by

Assume this is your model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then when you need a list of all tasks for a user you can just do

```
qs = Task.objects.filter(user=your_user_instance).order_by('-priority', 'created')
```

Now the variable qs is an iterator that lists the highest priority tasks first (And if two tasks have the same priority it'll list the older one first)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think this cater for users moving tasks up and down in priority. For example we have 5 tasks with priorities 1,2,3,4,5. The user then drags task 4 on the UI up above task 3. How would that play out in the db?

Comment: @darkpool Then you just update the database and change the priority to the new priority

Comment: Unfortunately we would run into a problem in this case: User moves priority 4 down to priority 3. We now have two priority 3's which is fine because we also order by created/updated date. Then the user tries to move priority 5 in between the two priority 3's,....that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i solved the above case for me

```
task_order_list = self.request.POST.get("task_order_list",'[]')
task_order_list = json.loads(task_order_list)

task_qs = Task.objects.all()
for priority,id in enumerate(task_order_list):
    task_qs.filter(id=id).update(priority=priority)
```

for the above snippet, suppose :

Actual list of task id's : [1,2,3,4,5]

**Input :**

New list  : [5,3,2,4,1]

**Output :**

updated list : [5,3,2,4,1]